# Android Service binding access control

Tags: android, android-service, ipc, access-control

I have an app which runs an activity in a separate process using the following tag in the manifest

```
android:process=:newProcess
```

I use a Service class, to allow the two processes to communicate. Now I want to enable some sort of access control so that only SPECIFIC activities can bind with and use the service.
Is such a thing possible?

I need this because I am working on an SDK and i want to make it difficult for users of the SDK to reverse engineer it. I don't want them to be able to bind to my service and get access to the data being used by my service.

One option is to pass a string to act as a key in the intent, and the onBind method of the service could validate the key and only allow the correct to bind, but the user of the sdk could simply see this key (as string would not get obfuscated by pro guard) and pass the key themselves and be able to bind to the service.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach i have thought of, is generating a UUID each time my SDK is invoked for an operation. That UUID will be accessible only within the scope of the SDK and hence the user cannot get an handle on it.
This uuid will be my key which i will pass via the intent, and only if this uuid matches will i allow the service to bind.
This ensures that only classes with access to that uuid will be able to bind to my service and also the uuid will regenerate on every invocation to my SDK.

I currently don't foresee any issues with this, but i might have missed out something.